# How to stop disconnecting when using ALFA wireless USB device?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, software-recommendation, drivers, devices

my Internet keep disconnecting every 3 minutes,
Ubuntu connected to Internet using my ALFA Wireless adapter AWUS036H without any drivers, but still i get disconnects..
should i install driver for my device?(i couldn't find it anyway)

Comment: Did you install all the updates?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's a usb 2.0 device it seems to require more than 500mA, so you need a usb Y cable (similar to one for an external hard drive) or a powered usb hub. I had the same issue until i realized it was a question of power requirements. The new cable completely solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks I will try this! On github some person mentioned similar solution https://github.com/P0cL4bs/WiFi-Pumpkin-deprecated/issues/243#issuecomment-577960991

Answer (score 1):

Before your Alpha antenna connects to an Internet server , disable it. 
Go to device manager, look for your Alpha wireless adapter , click on it , go to properties and change the channel to any other than 1. 
There may be a conflict in your computer with the built in wireless system and the Alpha antenna trying to use the same channel. 
Click on apply...
Restart everything, hopefully it will stay on...